# Unable to get data Posted by webhook in JSON String

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, webhooks

I am using web hook for get user details from our company's signup page.

Data posted from signup page in JSON format. Posted JSON String is below

```
{"FirstName":"dharampal","EmailAddress":"er.dpyadav@gmail.com","Mobile":"123456789","Company":"Instasafe","LandingPageURL":"http://instasafe.com/SignUp","LandingPageId":"11e2-b071-123141050daa"}
```

In receiving end, we are using PHP codeIgNiter, I tried below methods but unable to get data.

```
 $postedData = $_POST;
 print_r($postedData);
```

it gives : empty array

other method i tried is :

```
$postedData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);

print_r($postedData);
```

it gives : NULL

Comment: json string is the body of posted data? Can you show us how to posted the data?

Comment: we are using LeadSquared landing page for marketing purpose, they are sending data in JSON format and data is above given string. Please tell me at receiving end, am i doing right ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is a typo with `$ostedData` and `$postedData`

```
$ostedData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
print_r($postedData);
```